# Finding the corresponding columns associated with a row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD6s8.png)

Here is a data set is given.
The rows contain the different platforms.
The columns are the different genres.
We have the score associated with the platforms and the genres.
I have to find out the worst performing genre on PC. I used :

> genre = ign_data.loc['PlayStation Vita'].min()

I am able to get the worst performing score, However I am not able to extract the corresponding column associated with it. Does anyone know the solution to it?

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible example as well as dataset that is not in image format?

Answer (score 0):

Say I have this reduced `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["PS", 1, 6],
                   ["Switch", 2, 4],
                   ["SNES", 3, 0]], columns=["platform",
                                             "action",
                                             "adventure"])
```

[image]

The following command would add a new column called `min` to the `DataFrame` with the name of category where it has the worst score:

```
df['min'] = df.iloc[:, 1:3].idxmin(axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @luizbarcelos that solved my problem. Thank you!